# Is use of ReplaceAll() method forbidden in SonarQube

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube, replaceall

I have a simple method which replaces empty spaces with `'+'`. I have used `replaceAll()` method. However, when I run SonarQube, it detects the `replaceAll()` method as a vulnerability.
Below is the warning I get

> 'Make sure that using a regular expression is safe here.'

```
public static  String replaceSpace(String inputStr)
    {
        
        if(inputStr!=null)
        {
            return inputStr.replaceAll("\\s+" ,"+");

        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think SonarQube is confused, and validates the second argument as-if it is a regex.

Comment: It appears you are trying to encode a String in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.  Rather than using a regular expression, you should use [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLEncoder.html) for that.

Comment: Fully agree with @VGR .   For why you get the warning, it could be that regular expressions are open to Denial-of-Service attacks - see https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4784