# SonarQube regex security hotspot for replaceAll

Tags: java, sonarqube, replaceall

The following code flags a security hotspot in SonarQube due to backtracking when evaluating the regular expression which could lead to DoS. The regular expression is fine because it is not flagged elsewhere in the code, so this leads me to think SonarQube is flagging this because it is using ReplaceAll. I have read this post, [Is use of ReplaceAll() method forbidden in SonarQube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984300/is-use-of-replaceall-method-forbidden-in-sonarqube), but don't think this applies here.
My boss wants me to fix this wihtout using the //NOSONAR comment but not sure what needs fixing.

```
      final String MONGO_REG = "(mongodb://.+:)(.*)(@.+)";
      final String PASSWD_REPLACEMENT = "XXXXXXXXXX";
      String mongoUri = "mongodb://myDBReader:D1fficultP%40ssw0rd@mongodb0.example.com:27017/?authSource=admin";
      String newMongoUri = mongoUri.replaceAll(MONGO_REG, "$1" + PASSWD_REPLACEMENT + "$3");
      logger.info(">> {}", newMongoUri);
```

Using Java 11
Can anyone see how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall)

If you use it that way, you should use Pattern.compile instead. Sonarqube isn't able to check that you use a regular pattern.

Comment: @phillipschneider  

Thanks for responding!  
I replaced this statement with the following  


    `String newUrl = Patern.compile(MONGO_REG).matcher(mongoUri).replaceAll( "$1" + PASSWD_REPLACEMENT + "$3");`   

    Unfortunately SonarQube still flags the statement above with the Sonar Hot Spot as being security-sensitive. to DoS attacks due to backtracking.

Comment: Which code hast this Hotspot?

Comment: The code that has the SonarQube hotspot was
 
` 
String newMongoUri = mongoUri.replaceAll(MONGO_REG, "$1" + PASSWD_REPLACEMENT + "$3");  

replaced the statement above with:                                                                                                                                         String newUrl = Patern.compile(MONGO_REG).matcher(mongoUri).replaceAll( "$1" + PASSWD_REPLACEMENT + "$3");  
  
`
Both statement were flagged in SonarQube

Comment: Sorry, my fault: I meant the rule-id of the sonarqube-hotspot. E.g.

Comment: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2631